# Is there a way to convert an array of float** to Objective C and displaying those values

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

Currently working on a project that requires a iOS Wrapper and I need to translate data that is coming from C++ that is a float array (float*) to an array in Objective C (Assuming NSArray). I'll also need to display the values as well but I'm honestly confused in how to go about that, I tried memcpy but it doesn't seem to work, I think its because there is no way to access NSArray objects within memcpy.

Answer (score 1):

C++ float* and Objective-C float* are the same. Or write code in Objective-C++ if you have a C++ std::vector.

NSArray can only hold Objective-C objects, not float. But it would be a lot better to first find someone who knows Objrctive-C, possibly Swift, and knows what is actually needed.